# Cypress: Element is covered but still considered visible

Tags: cypress

Cypress's should('not.be.visible') assertion fails despite the element being covered. My goal is to ensure that the container div is not visible at this time. My original code is:

```
cy.get('#container').should('not.be.visible')
```

However, this assertion fails so I modified the code to:

```
cy.get('#container').should('be.visible').click()
```

Based on the previous assertion failing this should pass however I get the error below.

[image]